# Floating Action Button скрывается за фрагментом

Tags: java, android, android-layout

возникла следующая проблема: при запуске приложения кнопка Floating Action Button не видна на эмуляторе(API 24), однако видна на физическом устройстве(API 19), подскажите пожалуйста чем может быть вызвана проблема и как её решить, заранее спасибо!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_shape_gray"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:translationZ="8dp" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/draw_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/black_border"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.14" />


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/save_button_in_draw_fragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_save" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/table_name_in_draw_fragment_textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="Новая БД"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/save_button_in_draw_fragment"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.546"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/clean_image_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/clean_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_background"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clear" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/secondary_app_color"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:translationZ="12dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/secondary_app_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_bluetooth" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout >
```

Comment: Непонятно о каком фрагменте речь. И вкладывать `ConstraintLayout` в `ConstraintLayout` неправильно, он как раз и придуман, чтобы не заниматься вложениями.

Comment: Насчет вкладывания, сорри, поторопился, там первый `CoordinatorLayout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_shape_gray"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:translationZ="8dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/draw_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/black_border"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.14" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/save_button_in_draw_fragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_save" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/table_name_in_draw_fragment_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Новая БД"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/save_button_in_draw_fragment"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.546"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/clean_image_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/clean_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_background"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline8"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_clear" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:background="@color/secondary_app_color"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        android:translationZ="12dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/secondary_app_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_bluetooth" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!! не могли бы вы пожалуйста еще подсказать что именно я сделал не так, потому что в этом коде несколько строчек которые я не понимаю

Comment: @ДанилСычев ну например строчки 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

относятся именно к ConstraintLayout

Comment: а вы почему-то попытались их указать в coordinator layout

Comment: ещё раз большое спасибо!)

Answer (score 2):

Есть такой замечательный тул, `Layout Inspector`
https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Делаете с его помощью снимок экрана эмулятора и смотрите где же кнопка и почему не видна.

Comment: Я знаю где кнопка, она почему-то в нижнем слое, но ведь суть этой кнопки в том, чтобы она не перекрывалась, и вопрос именно в том что не так с xml кодом, потому что он сделан как на видео-примере с youtube, однако у меня работает не верно

Comment: Без кода трудно точно сказать. Проверьте visibility, может вы ее прячете или Z-order элементов меняется в коде. Разметка выглядит Ок.